# How do I check all list item ID's against a range of classes in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If this question has been asked, pardon the repeat.

I am not able to get my code to check every list ID against every possible class option in the ul class variable.

HTML:

```
<div class="category-filters-wrap">
    <ul class="ULClasses"> /* dynamic options that may contain multiple class options */
       <li id="Benefits">Item</li> /* Hard coded IDs */
       <li id="Resources">Item</li>
       <li id="Timecards">Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.category-filters-wrap').each(function() {

    $(this).find('li').each(function() {

        liID = $(this).attr('id'); /* Get ID from this list item */
        ULClass = $(this)closest('ul').attr('class'); /* Get Classes from closest UL to this list item */

        /* if the list ID matches ANY of the classes in the UL */
        if ($ (liID).hasClass(ULClass) ) {
            /* ... do stuff */
        }

    });

});
```

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
/* starting from if */
if (liID[1].match("(' + ULClass + ')") {
     /* ... do stuff */
}
```

and

```
/* starting from if */
if ($(liID).is(":contains('" + ULClass + "')")) {
     /* ... do stuff */
}
```

But I think I'm just throwing the kitchen sink at it at this point.
Thanks in advance for your help.  I'm relatively new to jQuery (pardon if I made some serious noobie mistakes).  If you have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong, the more detail you can provide to help me understand this, the better!

Gracias!

Comment: liID is a string, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Ah, I see the typos, my bad.  I was aware of the .closest (that was an error).  I was NOT aware of the # - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current jquery is "heavy" using find and closest.

Why not make life easier for yourself and assign each of the li tags a class (called "myclass" for example) then perform checks against them?  Granted, it the data is not long and your DOM page is short, then performance is not an issue - but in terms of good practice I would reconsider your seek and find thought process. The example below will search your page for all li tags that have a class "myclass" - when it finds one, it then checks to see if the li tag has class "anotherclass" and if it does, it does stuff...

```
$('li.myclass').each(function() {
        /* if the list ID matches ANY of the classes in the UL */
        if ($(this).hasClass("anotherclass") ) {
            /* ... do stuff */
        }
    });
});
```

OR the following one liner will find all li tags that have both myclass AND anotherclass and then do stuff...

```
$('li.myclass.anotherclass').each(function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

I hope the suggestion does not offend...

Comment: Not at all! I'm new to jQuery, so if it doesn't apply to this particular instance, It's still good to know other ways to handle a request, and I'm always interested in best practices.  Better to learn it the right way first, instead of the wrong way and having to undo it ;) 

Thank you for your suggestion/thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that iterates the classnames and return the classname found:

```
var searchClassName = function(string) {

  var arrayClasses = string.split(" ");

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayClasses.length; i++) {

    if($('#'+arrayClasses[i]).length > 0) {

      // the id with the className XXX was found!
      return arrayClasses[i];

    }

  }
  return false;
}
```

### Usage

```
searchClassName("string of classnames space separated");
// returns false if doesn't found
// returns the name of the classname found with id
```

### Whole snippet example:

```js
var searchClassName = function(string) {

  var arrayClasses = string.split(" ");

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayClasses.length; i++) {

    if($('#'+arrayClasses[i]).length > 0) {

      // the id with the className XXX was found!
      return arrayClasses[i];

    }

  }
  return false;
}



alert(searchClassName("Benefits Resources Timecards"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category-filters-wrap">
    <ul class="Benefits AnotherClassname">
       <li id="Benefits">Item</li>
       <li id="Resources">Item</li>
       <li id="Timecards">Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```